# Update a TDBGrid in C++ Builder

Tags: c++, sql, c++builder

Embarcadero's documentation on a lot of the DB components is incomplete and asks that users update it.  As a result I can't figure out how to get my `DBGrid` to update with a new SQL statement.

I have it call my SQL Statement just fine to begin with, however when I change the SQL statement and call the same update statement it still displays the original Grid.

I am using a `TDataSource` object to connect to my `TADOQuery` in order to fill my `DBTable`.  When I update my `TADOQuery` and have it rerun the query, then call the Update Function on my `DBGrid`, I see no difference.  Is there something extra I need to be doing with the `TDataSource`?

**Edit**: I copied the `TDataSource`, deleted the original, closed and opened Builder and it worked fine.

Comment: After you change your SQL statement, are you closing and opening the TADOQuery?  When you close and open the query, it will update the TDBGrid automatically. You don't need to manually call update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

copied the TDataSource, deleted the original, closed and opened Builder and it worked fine.